# .Where clause auto orders a list when testing, but not in production

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, entity-framework, nunit

I have a API endpoint that calls the below function to get the historic pass fail status of a piece of equipment:

This is the function which takes in an equipmentId from the controller:

```
var Id = GetId(equipmentId);
return new HistoricTestStatusDto
{
    EquipmentId = equipmentId,
    HistoricTestStatusDate = _dbContext.HistoricResultsQueryable
        .Where(x => x.Id == Id)
        .Select(f => new HistoricTestStatusDateDto
        {
            DateOfOperation = f.EventDate.Date,
            FailCount = f.NumberOfFails,
            PassCount = f.NumberOfPasses
        })
};
```

When this is returned via the API call, it comes back however the database (MS-SQL) returns it, which is normally not in DateOfOperation order.

`HistoricResults` is a view that does not order the results returned, so they could come back in any order.

```
[Table("HistoricResults")]
public class HistoricResults
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfFails { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPasses { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
}
```

I select this out into a new DTO HistoricTestStatusDateDto:

```
public class HistoricTestStatusDateDto
{
    public DateTime DateOfOperation { get; set; }
    public int PassCount { get; set; }
    public int FailCount { get; set; }
}
```

The EF model is set up like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<HistoricResults>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.EventDate });
```

### Testing

The below test should fail, as it shouldn't be ordered and I know I need to add a `.Order` after the `.Select`, however it passes due to the issue mentioned in this post.

The NUnit test setup uses a Sqlite in memory database:

```
private void CreateDatabase()
{
    _db = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
    _db.Open();
    _dbContext = new Context(CreateDb<Context>(_db));
    _dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

And the test looks like this, where the dateOfOperations are not in a specific order:

```
var dateOfOperation = new DateTime(2021, 11, 30);

_dbContext.HistoricResults.AddRange(new List<HistoricResults>
{
    CreateHistoricResult("Id1", EquipmentId1, dateOfOperation.AddDays(5)),
    CreateHistoricResult("Id1", EquipmentId1, dateOfOperation.AddDays(3)),
    CreateHistoricResult("Id1", EquipmentId1, dateOfOperation.AddDays(2)),
    CreateHistoricResult("Id1", EquipmentId1, dateOfOperation.AddDays(6)),
    CreateHistoricResult("Id1", EquipmentId1, dateOfOperation.AddDays(1)),
    CreateHistoricResult("Id1", EquipmentId1, dateOfOperation.AddDays(4)),
    CreateHistoricResult("Id1", EquipmentId1, dateOfOperation.AddDays(7))
});
_dbContext.SaveChanges();

var historicTestStatusDto = _sut.HistoricTestStatusCalc(EquipmentId1);
historicTestStatusDto.Should().NotBeNull();
historicTestStatusDto.HistoricTestStatusDate.Should().HaveCount(7);

historicTestStatusDto.HistoricTestStatusDate.Select(x => x.DateOfOperation).Should().BeInAscendingOrder();
```

When debugging the test and inspecting the `historicTestStatusDto.HistoricTestStatusDate` it appears to be in order even though I have not done any ordering, yet when called from the API in production it is returned in a random order (as sent back from the database view).

After more digging on this it seems that the `.Where` is actually ordering the data when testing with SQLite

```
_dbContext.HistoricResultsQueryable
        .Where(x => x.Id == Id)
```

**TL;DR**
Using a SQLite database when testing, the `.Where` clause seems to order by `DateOfOperation` ascending, however when running in production using MS-SQL it returns the data however it is returned from the database view.

Comment: when you don't provide an order _explicitly_, the order of the result is not defined and can always vary - you should _not_ rely on it; and yes, it _can_ be the order you want by chance. in your case it's dependent on the underlying database provider. if order is important _at all_, you _have_ to add your own `OrderBy()`.

Comment: If you need the data ordered, do tell the database to order it, otherwise there is no garantee you will get the data ordered as you need. In a similar way, if you use collections in your code, you should use [Sorted Collection Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/sorted-collection-types) to make sure the order is the one you want.

Answer (score -1):

The behavior you are seeing can be DB Provider implementation specific. Database systems build a query using indexes and other means and some providers might end up deriving result ordering based on factors from the index use or other things.

Specifying an order by clause states that the query is expected to provide results in a specific order.

Not specifying an order states that the consumer of the query ***does not care*** about the order of the result, so the mistake here is that your test is caring about the order...

Not specifying an order by does not mean "return by order added", or "return in random order", or certainly not "ensure these are not returned in order."